# Determining if $T_1=\{U\subseteq X:U=X \lor U\cap V=\emptyset\}$ is a topology and/or $T_2=\{U\subseteq X:U=X \lor U\cap V\neq \emptyset\}$

Tags: general-topology

$T_1=\{U\subseteq X:U=X \text{ or } U\cap V=\emptyset\}$ is a topology and/or $T_2=\{U\subseteq X:U=X \text{ or } U\cap V\neq \emptyset\}$
Where $V$ is a proper non empty subset of $X$.

I know for something to be a topology it must contain X and the empty set, arbitrary unions, and finite intersections.  I feel like the $T_2$ is not a topology because it would not include the empty set and I think $T_1$ is a topology but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What is $V$? An arbitrary subset of $X$ or something else?

Comment: Proper non empty subset of X

Comment: Your argument that the empty set is is not in $T_2$ indeed shows that this set is not a topology (However, your assumption $V \neq \emptyset$ is important here, since otherwise $X = \emptyset$ would be possible). If you believe that $T_1$ is a topology, you should consider a collection $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of subsets of $T_1$ and check if $\bigcup_i U_i$ intersects $V$ trivially (given that each $U_i$ intersects it trivially). Same for intersection (where $I$ is finite, even though this is not important here).

Answer (score 1):

T1 is a topology.  All the open sets other than X are a subset of V^c.

T2 is not a topology because empty set is not open.
If instead of "U = X or .." one used "U empty or ..", it is still
not a topology because two "open" sets without an "open" intersection
can be constructed, if V contains more than one point.  If V is a
singleton, T2, as amended above, would be a topology.